# How to solve non-linear sets of equations

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, sympy

I have a set of equations which can be expressed as a matrix and I also require that for all variables x<sub>i</sub> in the solution, (x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>3</sup> - x<sub>i</sub> = 0.For example,

```
A = [0 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 0]
    [1 0 0 1]
```

I also have that not all the variables = 0.

This means that

x<sub>2</sub> = 0
x<sub>3</sub> = 0
x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>4</sub> = 0
(x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>3</sup> - x<sub>1</sub> = 0
(x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>3</sup> - x<sub>2</sub> = 0
(x<sub>3</sub>)<sup>3</sup> - x<sub>3</sub> = 0
(x<sub>4</sub>)<sup>3</sup> - x<sub>4</sub> = 0

A simple solution is that x<sub>1</sub> = 1 and x<sub>4</sub> = -1.

How can you solve small instances of sets of equations like this? Preferably I would like a solution that is at least callable from python.

My current method to solve the problem is to try all 3<sup>n</sup> different vectors with values from -1,0,1.

```
for v in itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat = n):
    vector = np.asarray(v)
    if (not np.dot(M,v).any()):
        print "Solution found!"
        break
```

**EDIT**

This should be a comment to @alko's answer but it is too long. Let me work through the method with an example.

```
A = np.matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
p,l,u=scipy.linalg.lu(A)
print u
[[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.]]
```

I am not clear what the next step would be...?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: are your variables restricted to -1,0 and 1?

Comment: This looks more like a math question to me, why not try [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @lennon310 Yes that is what the terms x_i^3 - x_i = 0 enforces.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but there's also the trivial solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you put the SymPy tag, I'll point out that SymPy can solve this symbolically quite easily

```
In [6]: x1, x2, x3, x4 = symbols('x1:5')

In [7]: solve([x2, x3, x1 + x4, x1**3 - x1, x2**3 - x2, x3**3 - x3, x4**3 - x4], [x1, x2, x3, x4], dict=True)
Out[7]: [{x₁: -1, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: 1}, {x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: 0}, {x₁: 1, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: -1}]
```

Things can get more hairy if your solutions are not integers, as solutions by radicals might not exist, or at least SymPy might not be able to find them. If that were the case and you were only interested in numeric solutions you should stick with a numeric library like numpy or scipy, but since your solutions are all -1, 0, or 1, this is not an issue here.

**EDIT:**

If you have a Matrix, say:

```
A = Matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Then converting it to a system is easy. Just multiply it by a vector containing the symbols (I've switched to 0-based indexing here for convenience):

```
In [13]: syms = symbols("x:4")

In [14]: s = Matrix(syms)

In [15]: constraints = [xi**3 - xi for xi in syms]

In [16]: A*s
Out[16]:
⎡  x₁   ⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢  x₂   ⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣x₀ + x₃⎦

In [17]: solve(list(A*s) + constraints, syms, dict=True)
Out[17]: [{x₀: -1, x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 1}, {x₀: 0, x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0}, {x₀: 1, x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: -1}]
```

Here's the solution to your larger system:

```
In [35]: A = np.matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])

In [36]: A = Matrix(A).applyfunc(int)

In [37]: syms = symbols("x:7")

In [38]: s = Matrix(syms)

In [39]: constraints = [xi**3 - xi for xi in syms]

In [40]: solve(list(A*s) + constraints, syms, dict=True)
Out[40]:
[{x₀: -1, x₁: 1, x₂: 1, x₃: -1, x₄: 0, x₅: 1, x₆: -1}, {x₀: 0, x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: 0, x₅: 0, x₆: 0}, {x₀: 1, x₁: -1, x₂: -1, x₃: 1, x₄: 0, x₅: -1, x₆:
1}]
```

Two notes:

- You don't need to get it in LU. SymPy's solve will take care of that for you (you can start to worry about these things if your computation time gets too large).
- The `In [36]` converts the Matrix entries to ints (by default they are floats). It is not necessary, but in general, SymPy will do better with exact numbers when you know that they are exact, especially since you know your solutions are integers here anyway. If you use SymPy `Matrix` from the start, you won't need to worry about this.

Comment: Thanks. In my case n is the number of variables and the equations are defined by a matrix A which is created by another function. How can you get sympy to make the equations it needs from those?

Comment: I tried this in ipython but it failed. See edit to my question.

Comment: It seems you need 0.7.4 not 0.7.2. How do you do `syms = symbols("x:n")`  where n is a variable?

Comment: Also, if you set A to be an all zero matrix, the solve line just seems to hang. Do you get that too?

Comment: Yes you should use the latest version. 0.7.2 is actually quite old. If `n` is a variable just use string formatting: `symbols("x:%d" % n)`.

Comment: By the way, `dict=True` may not be the most convenient for you. If tuples are better, you can use `set=True`. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html.

Comment: Thanks. The real problem is that it just hangs when there are lots of solutions (I posted a separated question about this). For example if A is all zero.

Comment: In that case there are 3^n solutions, which could be quite large, and it is trying to find all of them.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is called Constraint programming. There are some python library that can solve this. For example the following code use [or-tools](https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/)

```
from constraint_solver import pywrapcp as cs
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 1]], np.bool)

#A = np.array( [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#               [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
#               [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
#               [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
#               [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], np.bool)

values = [-1, 0, 1]
solver = cs.Solver("name")
X = np.array([solver.IntVar(values) for i in range(A.shape[1])])
Xl = X.tolist()

for row in A:
    x = X[row].tolist()
    solver.Add(solver.Sum(x) == 0)

db = solver.Phase(Xl, 
                  solver.INT_VAR_DEFAULT, 
                  solver.INT_VALUE_DEFAULT)

solver.NewSearch(db)
while solver.NextSolution():
    solution = [x.Value() for x in Xl]
    print solution
```

output:

```
[-1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, -1]
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you add the constraint that at least one of the x in X1 must be non-zero?

Comment: I can't get pywrapcp to work. I just get "ImportError: cannot import name pywrapcp" despite doing "make install_python_modules" and also "sudo python setup.py install" in dependencies/sources/google_apputils_python-14/ just for good measure.

Comment: I got it to install in the end and now I have a segfault. I will post a separate query about this in the new year.

Comment: Looking at this again (and using the or-tools mailing list) it doesn't seem correct. The method doesn't use the values in A anywhere in the constraints!

Comment: @marshall, The code assume `A` is a bool array, and use `for row in A` to use every row in `A` as a mask array to select the variables in `X`. If the values in `A` are not all 0 & 1, then the constraints will be more complex, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to understand your solution.  `x=X[row].tolist()` just seems to be a list containing `DomainIntVar(-1..1)` repeated as many times as there are 1s row.  How does `solver.Sum(x)` work?

Comment: I would like to add a constraint that not all the solutions variables can be zero at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose `A` to [`lu` decomposition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
A = np.matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
               [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
               [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
               [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
p, l, u = scipy.linalg.lu(A)
```

For simplicity, let's assume that A has max rank, i.e. some of its proper minors is invertible. If it's not true, you can reduce matrix A to a smaller A' with the same LU decomosition as below, with A' satisfying this property and being equivalent in term of equation (last rows of `u` will be zeros, remove them and proceed). Your equation, `Ax=0` equals `(plu)x=0`, and as `p` and `l` are invertible matrices, `ux=0`. `u`, in turn is upper triangular

```
print u
# [[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.]]
```

You're interested only in last (two) columns, which defines all the variables in term of last variable value. Probing all x4 possible non zero values, `1` and `-1` you can check whether there is a solution to your set of equations:

```
from itertools import product
idx = u.shape[0] - u.shape[1] 
m, v = u[:, :idx], u[:,idx:]
for spare in product({1, 0, -1}, repeat=-idx):
    if any(spare): # to exclude all zeros
        sol = scipy.linalg.solve(m, -np.dot(v, spare))
        if not set(sol).difference({0,1,-1}):
            print 'solution: ', sol, spare
# solution:  [-1.  1.  1. -1. -0.] (1, -1)
# solution:  [ 1. -1. -1.  1. -0.] (-1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite see how to use this in general though.   I have added a worked example to the question.

Comment: @marshall I updated answer with your second example, as it is more general

Comment: Do you mean idx to be a negative number? u.shape[0] is 5 and u.shape[1]
 is 7.

Comment: @marshall as matrix is 5x7, idx=5-7=-2; abs(idx) is dimensionality of solution to Ax=0 if A has full rank (i.e. one have 7-5=2 spare variables). I could have used 7-5, but who cares? need both -2 and +2 in code.

Comment: Thank you. As my matrix will typically not be square and will be chosen at random I need to be able to handle the non max rank case too.  Should I just always do the lu decomposition as you say then remove all the zero rows from u and proceed?  In other words, just add  u = u[~np.all(u == 0, axis=1)] to the code.

Comment: I am having problems getting the code to work with degenerate matrices like [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0] even with the addition u = u[~np.all(u == 0, axis=1)] .  What should m be in this situation?

Comment: only meaning of this decomposition is to get invertible square matrix in left part of A, to be able to solve Ax=rest

Comment: @marshall sorry, out of time atm to explain in details degenerate case; but this is indeed a simple linear algebra, so hope you'll be able to proceed to a solution. it seems that lu isn't the only option, even needed, you need a way to find inverible minor of A; lu is one way for matrix of a full rank